# Simple slides with fades

Tags: javascript, slide, fade

Complete Java virgin. Was looking for quick way to create slide with fades and came across StackExchange. Jeff Miller provided this code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/2kkHH/) which I copied but mine gets stuck on first image....am I missing something. Here is my version of the code. I have simply lifted the code and put it all in one page. Tried in Firefox and Chrome...same issue. Any advice gratefully received. Thanks.

```js
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
    .next('img')
    .fadeIn()
    .end()
    .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 1000); // 4 seconds
```

```css
.fadein {
  position: relative;
  height: 320px;
  width: 320px;
}
.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadein">
  <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8359/8450229021_9d660578b4_n.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8510/8452880627_0e673b24d8_n.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8108/8456552856_a843b7a5e1_n.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8230/8457936603_f2c8f48691_n.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8329/8447290659_02c4765928_n.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript is the language you need to look at, not java. The two are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty (wont validate but hey ho)

[image: Stupid Code Blocks]

Comment: Thanks Alib_15....Just adding the ajax.googleapis.com did the trick. So do I always need such an link and therefore it wasn't shown in the original files from Jeff because it is "assumed"? Or is this link compensating for something not on my machine? Thanks again.

Comment: This is probably one of the best sources of info <http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp>